# Reply to Consumed Messages in Redis Stream

Tags: java, redis, publish-subscribe, redis-streams

I'm working with Java and Redis.

I have service A and Service B. Service A produced the messages and Service B consume those messages and do some processing. I want to reply to the same message which is send by the Service A. Service A need to get decision based on the response.

What is the best way to achieve this (request/response architecture) using the redis streams ?

Comment: Did you try to add another stream for acks?

Comment: Cant, we use the same stream? If we use another stream how can we co-relate the request and the response?